# Android how to show loaded images on RemoteViewsFactory of AppWidget implementing ListView

Tags: android, listview, widget, hashmap, android-appwidget

For showing loaded images on `appwidget`that has `ListView` on it,I

1. First download images
2. Store them on `HashMap<String,Bitmap>` where String is the url
3. Then on `RemoteViewsFactory  getViewAt()`,I simply `copy bitmap`and set it to `RemoteViews`
4. Then clear the `HashMap`
5. The `HashMap` is `static` and is `publicly` accessible

This works,but when I have two widgets then sometimes one of the `appwidget` has blank images.
If there are any working tutorial on it,it would be great.

Comment: When do you clear HashMap?